# Access multi index column names in groupby objects in pandas in for loop

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["ss", "ss", "ss", "xx", "xx", "xx"], "num":[1,1,2,1,1,2], "m":[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

[image]

```
def somefunction(m):
    mean = np.mean(np.array(list(m)))
    return mean

result = []

    for i,group in df.groupby(['name', 'num'], as_index=False):
        row_result = []
        mean = somefunction(group['m'])
        row_result = [group['name'], group['num'], mean ]
        result.append(row_result)


    headers = ['name', 'num', 'm']
    stats1 = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=headers)  
    stats1
```

With the above piece of code, my resultant dataframe looks like this.

[image]

But what I would really like to have is the following:

[image]

If I had used `apply` to perform the function, I could have just used `reset_index` to get what I wanted. But what I am computing has similar work flow to the example I gave below. Using `group['name']` or `group['num']` returns the entire series. How can I just get the group name and num in my final dataframe?

Ignore the function definition (it's just dummy), mine is much more complex than computing mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let use `groupby`, `mean`, and `reset_index`:

```
df.groupby(['name','num']).mean().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  name  num    m
0   ss    1  1.5
1   ss    2  3.0
2   xx    1  4.5
3   xx    2  6.0
```

---

Using your code, you can get groups via the `i`:

```
def somefunction(m):
    mean = np.mean(np.array(list(m)))
    return mean

result = []

for i,group in df.groupby(['name', 'num'], as_index=False):
    row_result = []
    mean = somefunction(group['m'])
    row_result = [i[0], i[1], mean ]
    result.append(row_result)


headers = ['name', 'num', 'm']
stats1 = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=headers)  
stats1
```

Output:

```
  name  num    m
0   ss    1  1.5
1   ss    2  3.0
2   xx    1  4.5
3   xx    2  6.0
```

Comment: About as perfect as can be.

Comment: @Scott Boston: Thanks!! That function was just a dummy function. My function definition is more complex!! I didn't know I could access them like i[0], etc. Thanks so much again!!

Comment: @pirsquared.  Thanks.